# How to quickly find the deepest subdirectory

Tags: filesystem

This self-answered question is more of a novelty or curiosity issue.

I know this can be done with a bash script that recursively traverses all directories. However it probably takes many hours to run.

***How can I quickly discover the deepest directory level?***

Answer (score 3):

### `locate` command is the fastest

The locate command is your friend in this case:

```bash
$ time locate "/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*"
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/java/services/personService/src/main/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonService.java
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/java/services/personService/src/test/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonServiceTest.java
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/javaWithCustomConf/services/personService/src/main/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonService.java
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/javaWithCustomConf/services/personService/src/test/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonServiceTest.java

real    0m1.731s
user    0m1.653s
sys     0m0.072s
```

Stuff in enough `/*/*` until no results are displayed, then subtract one `/*` to get the deepest subdirectory level. The files in the deepest levels will also be display.

**Note:** On this machine there are four different paths returned. Each path contains one file.

---

### Some details about locate

The database used by locate is updated daily by cron. If you installed an application or created new directories today you need update the database using:

```bash
sudo updatedb
```

In Ubuntu 19.10 the locate command is no longer installed by default. Hopefully it returns in 20.04 but in the meantime you need to install it with:

```bash
sudo apt install mlocate
```

To gain an appreciation of `locate` speed look at what it has indexed for instant retrieval:

```bash
$ locate -S

Database /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db:
    381,154 directories
    2,548,775 files
    213,049,136 bytes in file names
    92,287,412 bytes used to store database
```

---

### Using a script

Comments point out how people won't know the starting point. I wrote a script that defaults to 50 level starting point and works backwards from there. You can override with a starting point of 6 to 126 subdirectory levels.

#### Script output:

```bash
$ time deepdir

Search point 50 levels deep: /*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
Common path followed by unique sub-paths (deepest subdir 25 levels):
+- /mnt/clone/home/rick/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/
|--- /java/services/personService/src/main/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonService.java
|--- /java/services/personService/src/test/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonServiceTest.java
|--- /javaWithCustomConf/services/personService/src/main/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonService.java
|--- /javaWithCustomConf/services/personService/src/test/java/org/gradle/sample/services/PersonServiceTest.java

real    0m45.141s
user    0m44.552s
sys     0m0.588s

$ time deepdir 26

Search point 26 levels deep: /*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
Common path followed by unique sub-paths (deepest subdir 25 levels):
  (... SNIP repeated parts ...)

real    0m6.123s
user    0m6.041s
sys     0m0.080s
```

- The first time you run the script you don't know how deep the subdirectories go. Therefore the default of 50 levels will takes 43 seconds to run.
- The second time you run the script pass the known count + 1 and it only takes 6 seconds to run.
- After the second time, take the output line of `/*/*.../*` and copy it (less 1 set) to the clipboard as a parameter for calling `locate` or another command.

### The bash script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: deepdir
# PATH: $HOME/askubuntu/
# DESC: Answer for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187624/how-to-quickly-find-the-deepest-subdirectory/1187625?noredirect=1#comment1985731_1187625
# DATE: November 11, 2019.

StartLevel=50
[[ $1 != "" ]] && StartLevel="$1"
[[ $StartLevel -gt 126 ]] && { echo Max levels 126 ; exit 1 ; }
[[ $StartLevel -lt   6 ]] && { echo Min levels   6 ; exit 2 ; }

Big="/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" # 33
Big="$Big/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" # 31
Big="$Big/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" # 31
Big="$Big/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" # 31
                                                       # Total supported: 126

# If starting level populated it is too small.
Search="${Big:0:StartLevel*2}"
echo "Search point $StartLevel levels deep: $Search"
Count=$(locate "$Search" | wc -l)
[[ $Count -gt 0 ]] && { echo "Levels too small. $Count files found" ; exit 3 ; }

# Loop backwards to find first populated level, always more than 5
for (( l=StartLevel; l>5; l-- )) ; do
    Search="${Big:0:l*2}"
    Count=$(locate "$Search" | wc -l)
    [[ $Count -gt 0 ]] && break
done

Arr=( $(locate "$Search") )

# Enhancement using Q&A: Longest common prefix of two strings in bash
#                        https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475354/6929343

Common=\
"$(IFS=$'\n'; sed -e '$!{N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1\n\1/;D;}' <<<"${Arr[*]}")"
Common="${Common%/*}/"
echo "Common path followed by unique sub-paths (deepest subdir $l levels):"
echo "+- $Common"
Len="${#Common}"

for p in "${Arr[@]}" ; do
    # echo "DEBUG: $p"
    Curr="$(dirname "$p")"
    [[ $Curr != "$Last" ]] && echo "|--- /${p:$Len}"
    Last="$Curr"
done

exit 0
```

Comment: You could mention that running `sudo updatedb` may be needed in case files were added after the database was last updated. Also, in Ubuntu 19.10, the user needs to first install `mlocate` . It's [been dropped](https://askubuntu.com/q/1183750/248158) in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for suggestions. Answer updated.

Comment: How to determine "enough `/*`"?

Comment: @Fiximan In my case 25 levels deep in the sub-directory tree. You could start there and subtract or add levels as needed.

Comment: Well that assumes some pre-guess of the result and manual interaction. For pursuing your idea: How about defining the start directory and adding `/*` until `locate` has no result, then return the directory? Also you are not checking for subdirectories but files and thus will have to add a final `dirname(/path/to/file)` to get the directory only.

Comment: Is `locate` much faster than `ls -d` for this?

Comment: @Fiximan The script is hopefully perfect now...

Comment: @xenoid Using `time ls -d /*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*` took about 10 minutes before crashing. RAM was only 158MB free and then system (probably OOM killer I guess) closed the terminal tab. I had 5+ GB free after kernel killed it.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for asking. It led me to write a new Q&A on how to test out of memory conditions: [How to test oom-killer from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188024/how-to-test-oom-killer-from-command-line/1188025#1188025)

Answer (score 2):

```
find -type d \
  -wholename "$(find -type d -print0 |
                tr -d --complement '/\0' |
                sort -zur |
                sed 's:/:*/*:g' |
                head -z -n1 |
                tr -d '\0' )"
```

We'll use `find` to locate all directories, then select the one(s) with most slashes in the path. Notably we'll allow any possible names including odd characters such as newlines, spaces or whatnot.

Comment: Starting from root (`/`) you get permission denied errors which is a common complaint with `find` command versus `locate`. It processes virtual file systems such as `/proc`. On my system it takes 3 minutes versus 1 second for `locate` but it does eventually return the correct result so +1.

Comment: A well, I assumed you knew about a start directory and were not searching the whole system. Of course you could e.g. exclude some system dirs like `/proc` and `/sys`, redirect failures to not print `2> /dev/null` and even define a `-mindepth` (if you already have an idea about the result). Your approach is quicker, exactly because you added predefined minimal path lengths.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work OOTB for me with older GNU utils due to many problems. I gave up after working around the first one - old `head` version missing `-z` switch. IMO This approach is overcomplicated even though it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Really there's a much simpler way, `find` has a `-printf` action which has a `%d` format that prints the fs hierarchy depth.

### The oneliner

In order to get the 10 deepest dirs (starting in **cwd**) you just need to use:

```bash
find . -type d -printf '%03d %p\n' | sort -n -k 1 | tail -n 10
```

> **Alternatively** you can print the 10 biggest and unique depths by adding `-u` switch to `sort` command:
>
> ```bash
> find . -type d -printf '%03d %p\n' | sort -n -k 1 -u | tail -n 10
> ```

### Examples

Primary form of the command will output a list like this:

```tap
019 ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Test/Unit/Module/Di/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/etc/source/PhpExt.php
020 ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/View/_files/fallback/design/frontend/Vendor/default/ViewTest_Module/web/i18n/ru_RU
020 ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/_files/root/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Test/Unit/View
020 ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Module/I18n/Dictionary/_files/source/app/code/Magento/FirstModule/view/frontend
021 ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/_files/root/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Test/Unit/View/Element
```

### Performance

After dropping all VM caches with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` script was tested on a path with *41454* subdirs. Both variants took roughly the same amount of time:

```
real    0m6.310s
user    0m0.446s
sys     0m0.708s
```

This was performed on a relatively underpowered server with the disk hard-limited to *3000 IOPS*.

### Notes

The script was tested under **CentOS 7**, not Ubuntu, however, I think it should be pretty portable across shells with GNU utils.