# how do I find openjdk-11 that I just installed?

Tags: software-installation, openjdk, jdk

I'm currently trying to install `ghidra` on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. While installing, I get this:

```
******************************************************************
JDK 11+ (64-bit) could not be found and must be manually chosen!
******************************************************************
Enter path to JDK home directory (ENTER for dialog):
```

So, I think cool, and run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

If I now run `whereis java`:

```
/usr/share/java$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

So I cd to the first directory, ans look:

```
/usr/share/java$ ls
commons-logging-1.2.jar           java-atk-wrapper.jar  pdfbox-1.8.16.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.2.jar  java_defaults.mk      pdfbox.jar
commons-logging-adapters.jar      java_uno.jar          ridl-6.4.7.jar
commons-logging-api-1.2.jar       juh-6.4.7.jar         ridl.jar
commons-logging-api.jar           juh.jar               unoloader-6.4.7.jar
commons-logging.jar               jurt-6.4.7.jar        unoloader.jar
fontbox-1.8.16.jar                jurt.jar
fontbox.jar                       libintl.jar
```

Here is a bunch of jar files? Usually the jdk has a `bin` folder and so on?

I also try giving `/usr/share/java` to the ghidra installation, but it complains that this is not a valid jdk home directory because it is missing a `bin` folder.

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin` as `PATH`

Comment: Remember that `whereis` only knows about binary / source / man pages. Probably the installation is looking for somewhere like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: `update-alternatives --display java` please add this to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have previously checked with `whereis` whether your binary is installed,
now you can check if it can be executed properly :

- does its location belong to your PATH variable ? try the command `which java` and it should return something like `/usr/bin/java`
- is it a valid binary then ? try to display its version using the command `java -version` and it should display something like

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- also keep in mind that some java applications may need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Then you can set it to the home dir of your java install, for example `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

To help you to retrieve the java home path you can use `which java  | xargs realpath` which provides a path like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` (or you can use `ls -l` several times on the path provided by `which`) from which you need to remove the latest part `/bin/java`.

PS :
be careful with the fact that if you need several java runtimes on your system, then the PATH resolution and the JAVA_HOME must match to the same version.
At your  convenience, you can unzip any specific version in any folder like /my/custom/install/jdk15/
and override the system paths :

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/my/custom/install/jdk15
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

On my system I set JAVA_HOME inside my .bashrc using a command that looks like this :

```
export JAVA_HOME=`dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))`
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure the installation was done correctly by running `java --version`, you should see something like:
[image]

Then, in order to locate the jdk folder, run the command below:

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

It returns the path, in my case it returns:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

you can run `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` and it will show the jdk folder content. It'd look something like:
[image]

## Details

### Why

First `whereis`! Just like `which` doesn't resolve symlinks!

`which java` => give Command path => return a symlink to a symlink

Example in debian:

`/usr/bin/java` =symlink to=> `/etc/alternatives/java` =symlink to=> `/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` is the actual java binary! And `/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64` is the java home.

If you want to use whereis! One need to resolve the symlinks too! And here recursively!

Symlink => Symlink => Actual folder or file

We can do that through read link

### Readlink

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readlink-command-in-linux-with-examples/

> readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names

In short! if you have a symbolic link!

`readlink symbolicLink` => Will give what it resolve to

given `Symlink1 => Symlink2 => path`

`readllink Symlink1` =return=> Symlink2

`readlink Symlink2` =return=> path`

Here let's see it with java:

[image]

A one command

[image]
Yup that's ugly!

And there is better! Use the `-f` flag

from the help doc

```
 -f, --canonicalize            canonicalize by following every symlink in
                                every component of the given name recursively;
                                all but the last component must exist
```

So:

```sh
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Recursivly resolve the symlinks!

[image]

You can use that through whereis too!

[image]

You can see and can find your home directory!

Using `which` in this context! Is better then whereis!

For the difference between `which` and `whereis`! Let's use `whatis`

```
$  whatis which
which                (1)  - shows the full path of (shell) commands

$  whatis whereis
whereis              (1)  - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `whereis` and `find` command is the `locate` command. It is extremely fast:

```
$ locate openjdk | head -n10
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream/CollectorOps.java
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream/DoubleStreamTestDataProvider.java
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream/DoubleStreamTestScenario.java
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream/FlagDeclaringOp.java
/home/rick/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/org/openjdk/testlib/java/util/stream/IntStreamTestDataProvider.java
```

These are the first 10 filenamess containing `openjdk`. You can quickly locate and count the number of files using `wc` (word count) command with the `-l` (line count) parameter:

```
$ time locate java | wc -l
57555

real    0m0.945s
user    0m0.927s
sys     0m0.021s

$ time locate openjdk | wc -l
72

real    0m1.053s
user    0m1.033s
sys     0m0.021s
```

So there are 57,555 files with`java` in the filename and 72 files with `openjdk` in the filename. In both instances it takes about 1 second to find them all.

To truly appreciate the speed of the `locate` command consider searching which filenames contain the letter `e` which is the most common letter in the alphabet:

```
$ time locate e | wc -l
2283738

real    0m0.580s
user    0m0.592s
sys     0m0.177s
```

There are 2,228,738 files with the letter `e` occuring at least once in their filename. This is for three Ubuntu installations, one Windows installation and one shared Ubuntu + Windows partition. It only takes 1/2 a second to locate them!

You may have to install the `locate` command first:

- [Ubuntu 19.10: why is the "locate" command missing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183750/ubuntu-19-10-why-is-the-locate-command-missing)